# Learning Blender. Add custom hyperlink button to UI to navigate to browser

Tags: customization

Is there a simple way to add a hyperlink to a custom button (preferred) or menu in the Blender Gui?

My basic need at the moment is to open up links to documentation (especially hot keys https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Hotkeys/All)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bpy.ops.wm.url_open()` to open a url from a button.

For example, using the *UI Panel Simple* template (from the *Text Editor> Templates> Python*) you can add this to the `draw` method:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("wm.url_open", text="Open Link").url = "http://www.google.co.uk"
```

This will display a button whose sole purpose is to open a link. If you already have a button and just want to add this extra functionality, you can call the operator directly with:

```
bpy.ops.wm.url_open(url="http://www.google.co.uk")
```

Comment: Noticed the edit.. to  call in  code needs keyword name and (possibly too) tthe protocol `bpy.ops.wm.url_open(url="http://google.com")`

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks, couldn't figure out what I was missing.

Comment: ... definitely needs the protocol eg http:// .. othewise, on ubuntu for example, creates a blend file path plus url file link.

Comment: @batFINGER Ok. I had only tested on windows, which was fine.